# Pyfst installation on windows 7 fails

Tags: python, pycharm, openfst

I have been struggling to install [Pyfst](http://pyfst.github.io/) for days. After resolving the issue with vcvarsall and installing Visual Studio C++ tools, I ran into another issue, for which I cannot find the answer online (for **Windows 7**). I am trying to install it with **PyCharm** and I tried for both **Python 2.7** and **Python 3.5**. I get this error:

```
Collecting pyfst
  Using cached pyfst-0.2.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyfst
  Running setup.py install for pyfst: started
    Running setup.py install for pyfst: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\pyth\pythonw.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pyfst\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ykez_6hi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fst
    copying fst\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fst
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building 'fst._fst' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\fst
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\pyth\include -IC:\pyth\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /EHsc /Tpfst/_fst.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\fst/_fst.obj -O2
    _fst.cpp
    fst/_fst.cpp(321): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fst/symbol-table.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------

Command "C:\pyth\pythonw.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pyfst\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ykez_6hi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pyfst\
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck using the Python bindings that are included in OpenFST 1.5+.

http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/PythonExtension